# React Router Dom action with axios

Tags: reactjs, axios, react-router

In react-router, I'm using action to send a post request to the backend when the form is submitted. those are all working problem is I want to return response and errors that come from the backend. I'm returning those in axios then and catch function but in UI it shows undefined.

```
export async function registerAction({ request }) {
  const formData = await request.formData();

  const response = await apiClient.get("/sanctum/csrf-cookie").then((response) => {
    apiClient
      .post("/register", {
        first_name: formData.get("first_name"),
        last_name: formData.get("last_name"),
        full_name: formData.get("full_name"),
        email: formData.get("email"),
        //birthday: formData.get("birthday"),
        address: formData.get("home_address"),
        phone_no: formData.get("phone_number"),
        ssn: formData.get("ssn"),
        password: formData.get("password"),
        password_confirmation: formData.get("password_confirmation"),
      })
      .then((response) => {
        return response;
      })
      .catch((errors) => {
        return errors;
      });
  });

  return null;
}
```

Comment: You need to return `response.data;`  not only `response;` and same things apply with `error`

Comment: @DSDmark it doesn't matter always returns that last null return. those other statements are not returning. that's the problem.

Comment: try to return your whole post request like this `return apiClient.post("/register", {......` with `response.data;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `registerAction` action function is simply returning `null` to the UI. It should return the result of the axios requests, e.g. the Promise chain.

Example:

```js
export async function registerAction({ request }) {
  const formData = await request.formData();

  return apiClient.get("/sanctum/csrf-cookie")
    .then(async (response) => {
      await apiClient.post("/register", {
        first_name: formData.get("first_name"),
        last_name: formData.get("last_name"),
        full_name: formData.get("full_name"),
        email: formData.get("email"),
        //birthday: formData.get("birthday"),
        address: formData.get("home_address"),
        phone_no: formData.get("phone_number"),
        ssn: formData.get("ssn"),
        password: formData.get("password"),
        password_confirmation: formData.get("password_confirmation"),
      });
      return response;
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      return error;
    });
  });
}
```

Or using straight `async/await`/`try/catch`.

```js
export async function registerAction({ request }) {
  const formData = await request.formData();

  try {
    const response = await apiClient.get("/sanctum/csrf-cookie");
    await apiClient.post("/register", {
      first_name: formData.get("first_name"),
      last_name: formData.get("last_name"),
      full_name: formData.get("full_name"),
      email: formData.get("email"),
      //birthday: formData.get("birthday"),
      address: formData.get("home_address"),
      phone_no: formData.get("phone_number"),
      ssn: formData.get("ssn"),
      password: formData.get("password"),
      password_confirmation: formData.get("password_confirmation"),
    });
    return response;
  } catch(error) {
    return error;
  };
}
```